# Cannot run project which has Maven integration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I installed Maven to be able to easily import / manage dependencies for `org.apache.commons:comons-lang3:3.1`. After opening `pom.xml` the project can not be run or debugged.
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>deleteme</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The Run and Debug buttons became inactive.
[image]

Comment: You probably miss an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Maven can download help you do download require libraries but will not run the app for you.

Comment: When I click `Tools>Run` it suggest to edit `Run configuration`. I have no idea what to put there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing with maven. It about IntelliJ setup!
Actually, maven has slightly different file structure

```
/project-root
  /src
    /main
      /java <-- put your sources here
      /resources
    /test
      /java 
      /resources
/your-packages-and-sources <-- now your sources is probably here
pom.xml
```

Try to:

- right click on your project and "Add framewrok support" select maven.
- right click on your package and "Mark directory as" -> "Source root"
- copy your sources to maven source dir -> src/main/java

Comment: `Add framewrok support` there is no Maven, only Groovy

Comment: It is very likely the maven support is enabled already. Do you have created maven-like structure, that with src/main/java? And try to mark your directory with packages as "Source root" it should help! You can manage it also trough "Project structure" (hit F4)

Comment: Awesome, it works! Why there is no Maven in `Add framework support` then?

Comment: No idea. As i said you probable had maven enabled and enabled framework supports are not longer visible in "Add framework support" menu.